# Matlab gamma correction when opening and writing files

Tags: matlab, gamma

I am using matlab to do some calculations on images, and my first impression was that the values stored in a matlab matrix after reading from a jpeg file were gamma-corrected. Hence, I should write the following code:

```
im = (double((imread('Myimage.jpg')))/255).^2.2;
```

in order to get a matrix with values in linear space. However, I tried the following: generate a linear gradient:

```
for x=1:256
gradient(:,x) = ones(128,1) * (x-1)/255;
end
```

Then I write this to a jpeg file and read it again:

```
imwrite(gradient, 'gradient.jpg', 'Quality', 100);
gradient_jpg = double(imread('gradient.jpg'))/255;
```

Now I would expect gradient and gradient_jpeg to be different, as the latter was gamma-corrected when written as a jpg file and the other was not. Turns out both matrices are the same. And I this is where I don"t understand. In a previous test, I tried opening the same jpg image from matlab and HDRShop. Both images look the same on-screen, but when I lookup the values in the images, they are not the same. The values in matlab happen to be the values I get in HDRShop at the power of 2.2 (roughly).
So myquestion is ... does matlab store the values in linear space when it reads a jpeg file, or do I have to specifically apply a gamma term (.^2.2) in order to get linear values?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. I'm here for the same reason.

In the docs for imread, I see no options for gamma correction, and it's silent on the whole issue.

I get the same values in the matrix that I read off the screen (from imshow, using a color checker utility). And the values I see on screen are very close (but not exactly the same) to what I see in other image viewing apps.

So I'm not sure this is an answer, but there's some more info.

Comment: I've ended up going with assuming gamma 2.2 for all images and opening them as (double(imread('im.whatever'))/255)^2.2

Answer (score 0):

Actually, MATLAB provides `rgb2lin`and `lin2rgb` functions to do gamma decompression/compression. In the following example, when writing directly the gradient, and adding a 0/1 checkerboard below, you can easily see that 50% gray (which is the checkerboard value) does not correspond to 0.5 in the gradient:

[image]

But if you apply lin2rgb before writing, this is what you obtain, and 50% gray is now the middle value:

[image]

Here is the MATLAB code:

```
gradient = zeros(128,256);
for x=1:256
    gradient(1:64,x) = ones(64,1) * (x-1)/255;
    for y = 64:128
        gradient(y,x) = mod(x+y,2);
    end
end
imwrite(gradient, 'gradient.png');
gradient_g = lin2rgb(gradient);
imwrite(gradient_g, 'gradient_g.png');
```